# Display PID and Port of running processes

Tags: linux, unix, command, system

I have a task where I have to display the PID and Port number of running processes/tasks in Linux. What I have done so far is:

`ps -ef | awk '/[t]ick/{print "PID="$2" "$9}'`

Can anyone tell me how do I also display the port of the returned results? Here is what Im getting returned currently:
[image]

Comment: can you post `ps ..|grep tick`  output?

Comment: Hey, I attached an example

Comment: can we see the whole "tick" line..  `ps ..|grep tick`  whitout `awk`

Comment: `netstat -anp | grep LISTEN` will give you all ports listening on your system, with PID associated to each port (option `-p`).